# How to get access to beta device logs using Apple's TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

In the old TestFlightApp, there was an SDK that allowed developers to log info on the device and then access those logs from the TestFlight website.

After the Apple takeover of TestFlight, I'm not seeing an option to do this through iTunes Connect.

Does anyone know of a way to do this using Apple's new version of TestFlight? Or does anyone have any recommendations for a simple approach to viewing device logs during beta testing?

Comment: Apple ruined TestFlight since they took it over, in so many ways. This is just one example of something that used to be easy but now isn't.

Answer (score 3):

If you can get your beta testers to send you log files manually, you have a few options. You used to be able to use the iPhone Configuration Utility to view device log files, but it no longer works as of iOS8. The only OS X tool to view device logs other than Xcode that I've been able to find is iOS Console from Lemon Jar Labs (http://lemonjar.com/iosconsole/). It's a very nice tool and I actually prefer it to the Xcode console log - I especially love the filtering ability. I've also seen reference to iTools (http://www.itools.cn/) that works under Windows being able to access device log files, but have no personal experience with it.